# Why is the field empty when I use a multiple case when?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, case-when

I have this SQL Code:

```
SELECT (  P1.Name
    + (CASE P1.Vorname WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + P1.Vorname END)
    + (CASE (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort)
          WHEN '' THEN ''
          ELSE ' - ' + (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort)
       END)
    + (CASE (PKT1.Kennung + PKM1.Kennung)
          WHEN ''
          THEN
             ''
          ELSE
               ' - '
             + (CASE PKT1.Kennung
                   WHEN '' THEN ''
                   ELSE 'Tel: ' + PKT1.Kennung
                END)
             + (CASE PKM1.Kennung
                   WHEN '' THEN ''
                   ELSE ' Mobil: ' + PKM1.Kennung
                END)
       END))
      AS [IO1] FROM XYZ
```

Now when one field is not filled, the cell is empty.
When everything is filled with data the cell gets filled.

So what is the Problem with that code?

I have to work with MSSQL Server 2005 so CONCAT or whatever will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT (P1.Name +
        (CASE P1.Vorname WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + P1.Vorname END) +
        (CASE (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort) WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE ' - ' + (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort) END) + 
        (CASE (PKT1.Kennung + PKM1.Kennung) WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE ' - ' + (CASE PKT1.Kennung WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE 'Tel: ' + PKT1.Kennung END) +
        (CASE PKM1.Kennung WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE ' Mobil: ' + PKM1.Kennung END) END)
       ) AS [IO1]
FROM XYZ;
```

It is going to produce `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`.  Presumably one or more of the columns is `NULL`.  You can fix this by wrapping things in `coalesce()` and/or changing the `case` statements.  For instance:

```
SELECT (coalesce(P1.Name, '') +
        (CASE WHEN P1.Vorname = '' or P1.Vorname is null THEN '' ELSE ', ' + P1.Vorname END) +
        (CASE WHEN (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort) = '' or (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort) is null THEN '' ELSE ' - ' + (AP1.Postleitzahl + AP1.Ort) END) + 
        (CASE WHEN (PKT1.Kennung + PKM1.Kennung) = '' or (PKT1.Kennung + PKM1.Kennung)  is null THEN '' ELSE ' - ' + (CASE WHEN PKT1.Kennung = '' or PKT1.Kennung  is null THEN '' ELSE 'Tel: ' + PKT1.Kennung END) +
        (CASE WHEN PKM1.Kennung  = '' or PKM1.Kennung is null THEN '' ELSE ' Mobil: ' + PKM1.Kennung END) END)
       ) AS [IO1]
FROM XYZ;
```

Comment: Oh thank you! 

Yeah it is kinda obvious when i look at it now.

Comment: @benerawr do not forget to mark this answer as real answer if it is correct.

Comment: i will but i have to wait 2 more minutes. >_>